# unable to use Crontab in Linux?

Tags: operating-system

i use fallowing command to excute my script in every 30 min
*/30 * * * * /home/g-m-iqbal/Desktop/Auto/algo.sh

and also try this
*/30 * * * * /home/g-m-iqbal/Desktop/Auto/ && sh algo.sh

here

/home/g-m-iqbal/Desktop/Auto this the path of script

Comment: What is your question? What is going wrong? What error message are you getting?

Comment: i get no error but on this schdueling is also not working it is not excuting .sh on given time

Comment: You need to remember that the cron jobs don't have access to the login shell, so any environment variables in your script will need to be set in the script, not relying on something from your login profile.  there should be messages in your log files, in `/var/log`, or in the `dmesg` command. have you looked there?

Comment: the first one might fail depending on your file exec permissions. the second would fail because it is wrong. you could change the second command to:`*/30 * * * * "cd /home/g-m-iqbal/Desktop/Auto/ && sh algo.sh"`